# Powershell - Process files if there is more than one row in the text file

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. We have multiple text files in sFTP location, which are need to be scanned, if there is more than one row in the files then move to a loading process if there is only one records ignore them and not load them.

I am able to get count of rows by using the below code but it is not giving me expected results. Not sure how to achieve this. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$paramDest = "C:\\All\" 
Get-ChildItem $paramDest -Filter *.txt | 
ForEach-Object { $content = (Get-Content $_.FullName -Delimiter "`r`n" | Measure-Object).Count 
$content | Set-Content $_.FullName 
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "*not giving me expected results.*". What do you expect and what is the actual result?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which you requested.

If txt file have equal 2 or more than 2 rows then then it will proceed the script.

```
$txtfile="C:\Users\test\Desktop\test.txt"
$content = Get-Content $txtfile -Force 
$rowcount=($content.Count)-1
If($rowcount -ge 2){
#Paste you command Here
}
```

**Update1:**
Please find below code for multiple file:

```
    $file_have_2_line = $null
    $file_have_2_line = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    $sftp_path="C:\Users\test\Desktop"
    $total_txt_file = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $sftp_path -Filter *.txt -Force -Recurse  | %{$_.fullname})
    $total_txt_file = $total_txt_file |  ? { $_ } | sort -uniq
    
    Foreach($txt in $total_txt_file){
    $content = Get-Content $txt -Force 
    $rowcount=($content.Count)-1
    If($rowcount -ge 2){
    $file_have_2_line += $txt
    }}
Write-Host $file_have_2_line
```

You get all file list in $file_have_2_line variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I need to handle multiple files here, struggling with the final code. Please find the below code. Can you please suggest.

$paramSou = "C:\Users\test\" 
Get-ChildItem $paramSou -Filter *.txt | 
ForEach-Object { $content = Get-Content $_.FullName -Force 
$rowcount=($content.Count)-1 
If($rowcount -ge 2) { 
Copy-Item -Path $paramSou\*.txt -Destination $paramDest2
}

Comment: I have update the answer and please if your issue resolved then you can accept the answer.